# why is this type of variable not compatible with string?

Tags: python

I am trying to ask the user what they want to name a file that is about to be created on my desktop. When I try to add the variable to the string, it gives me this error:

```
appendFile = open('%s.txt', 'a') % cusername
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'str'
```

Here is my program:

```
def CNA():
    cusername = input("Create username\n>>")
    filehandler = open("C:/Users/CJ Peine/Desktop/%s.txt", "w") % cusername
    filehandler.close()
    cpassword = input("Create password\n>>")
    appendFile = open('%s.txt', 'a') % cusername
    appendFile.write(cpassword)
    appendFile.close()
    print ("Account Created")
```

How do I make the variable compatible to the string?

Comment: The `% cusername`  needs to be with `'%s.txt'` and not with `open()`

Comment: `open(...)` supposed to return a file-handler. what's the meaning of `file_handler % cusername` ?

Comment: when i do that a text file shows up on my desktop with % cusername instead of the variable i put in.

Comment: @CJPeine: what variable you are referring to? ("C:/Users/CJ Peine/Desktop/%s.txt" % cusername ... should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
cusername = input("Create username\n>>")

filehandler = open("C:/Users/CJ Peine/Desktop/" + cusername + ".txt", "w")
```

instead. Or you're just trying use modulus operator `%` on `open` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator for formatting strings [should take a string `str` as a first argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) but instead you're passing the object returned from `open(...)`. You can use this expression instead:

```
open("C:/Users/CJ Peine/Desktop/%s.txt" % cusername, "w")
```

Alternatively, [Python 3 supports using the `str.format(str)` method (`"C:/Users/CJ Peine/Desktop/{}.txt".format(cusername)`)](https://pyformat.info/), which IMHO is much more readable, and Python 3 is much better than Python 2 anyway. [Python 2 has been out of active development for ages and is scheduled to no longer be supported](https://pythonclock.org/); please don't use it unless you absolutely have to.